# A definitive way to detect Java source level in a multi-module Maven and Gradle projects?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

What are the definitive ways (preferably command line) to detect the source compatibility (i.e. the value of `-source` flag on `javac` command) of **multi-module** Maven and Gradle projects?

Here's what I have tried with limited success:

1. `mvn help:effective-pom` will sometimes print out the `<source>1.x</source>` line in its output for the `maven-compiler-plugin`.
2. Maven projects may sometimes have the `<maven.compiler.source>` *property* (like e.g. `<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>`) which seems to override the plugin configuration. (Go figure).
3. The Gradle task `gradle properties` will produce a property `sourceCompatibility: 1.x` but only for a single-module project.

Given this *variability*, what is a dependable way to get what I need? Note that the intent of the tool I want to develop is to examine existing Maven/Gradle projects and see if they are at the right Java source level. If there is another way of doing what I want, please suggest that as well.

Comment: Seems you already have the answers yourself. Note that it is *your* job is to examine each Maven/Gradle project and determine the source level using the methods you described, and then collect that data.

Answer (score 0):

And sometimes it is not specified, and different maven/java installations will yield different java versions. For the rest compiling with verbose might help. Or better **inspect the .class version byte inside the jars**.

The easiest might be to have a single root pom with version specified, and all other module poms be cleansed of versions: either property or compiler plugin. Maybe together with checking the dependencyManagement in the root pom.

Comment: The trouble is I don't have any control over the pom.xml's of the projects my tool is presented with. The tool is supposed to find out what Java language compatibility the sources have (clarified it in the post).

Comment: Then scan the built classes. The rest is guess work; worth a go, but not decisive.

Comment: I agree. In scanning the maven compiler source code it appears to me that when plugin configuration does not say anything about `<source>` it is the `maven.compiler.source property` that decides the version. A [very recent commit](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-compiler-plugin-3.6.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/AbstractCompilerMojo.java?annotate=1766731#l87) upgraded the default version to 1.5.